# Record audio through HTML5 API (RecordJS or alternative) to AAC

Tags: javascript, html, audio-recording

I need to record an audio files, export (store into the server) it to aac format, get it's link and send the link plus the actual audio (aac) file to a RESTful WS.

I found this library to record audio (taking advantage of HTML5 Audio API): **RecordJS** https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs

I set it up (init + start recording + stop recording).
Now I'm supposed to **process the audio in order to export it**.

The example provided by the plugin creator is:

```
  function createDownloadLink() {
    recorder && recorder.exportWAV(function(blob) {
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      var au = document.createElement('audio');
      var hf = document.createElement('a');

      au.controls = true;
      au.src = url;
      hf.href = url;
      hf.download = new Date().toISOString() + '.wav';
      hf.innerHTML = hf.download;
      li.appendChild(au);
      li.appendChild(hf);
      recordingslist.appendChild(li);
    });
  }
```

The example provided is quite straightforward.
However, I have no clue on how

1. actually **getting an aac audio files**
2. **store it** (the example shows how to download, not how store on server)
3. **get the file's link** (server's path).

I'm sorry I can't provide a working fiddle but I'm quite new and confused about HTML5 API.

I can use another library or pure HTML5 API if needed. Just need some clue on how to proceed. Even a generic solution (i.e. not just export to AAC but also MP3 or whatever) is fine if this can be helpful to others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The example provided is quite straightforward. However, I have no clue on how
>
> 1. actually getting an aac audio files

You can't...  at least not directly not today.  I think the MediaRecorder API aims to solve this but it isn't really supported yet, nor is it standardized.

Some folks have used [emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten) to build LAME for MP3 encoding.  You could try to do the same for an open source AAC encoder, such as the one built into FFmpeg.  Check out [videoconverter.js](https://bgrins.github.io/videoconverter.js/).  Note that this is very slow, highly experimental, and not appropriate for all use cases.

> 2. store it (the example shows how to download, not how store on server)

Use whatever you want to send that data to the server.  If it were me, I'd send it over a binary web socket.

> 3. get the file's link (server's path).

That depends on what you do with it server-side, which we cannot answer for you.  It's whatever you want.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know either my solution will answer your question. First, you have to convert the blob format to URL format inorder to transfer it. After that, use ajax to upload it to the server. The url will be converted to AAC format at server side using PHP scripting.

in javascript:

```
function saveToServer() 
{
       recorder && recorder.exportWAV(function(blob) {
       var data = "";
       var reader = new FileReader();
       reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
       reader.onloadend = function(){
          data =  reader.result;
          //your ajax code here
       }

       });

}
```

Example of php script:

```
$audioData = substr($_POST['data'], strpos($_POST['data'], ",") + 1);
$decodedAudioData = base64_decode($audioData); 
$upload_dir = "/this/is/AAC/directory/";  
mkdir($upload_dir); //create dir
$aacFile = $upload_dir."myAudio.aac";  // create AAC file  in the dir 
$fileHandle = fopen($aacFile, 'wb');
$fwrite($fileHandle, $decodedAudioData); // write data into the AAC file
$fclose($fileHandle);
```

I did this thing a week ago and please don't follow exactly the above code I wrote, bcoz I'm just giving rough idea how to store AAC format from RecordJS to server. I didn't check the syntax of my code above.

The only way to transfer the recorded audio is to convert it into URL format in javascript. It is impossible to transfer blob or AAC file from web browser to server.